# state of art paradigm? 1 website for browser and mobile or 2 different websites

Tags: web-development, mobile

I would like to know what the standard aproach for mediumsized websites is, if you want to have users with browser and mobile.

Make 1 Website with a lot of if-else because of browser/mobile or make 2 seperated websites?

When do u make 1 website for browser/mobile and when do u make 2 different websites?

Answer (score 3):

The current trend of [responsive web design](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/) makes it possible to serve the *exact* same content to a desktop browser and mobile browser and have it display well for both systems. If you are starting your design from scratch, or your HTML is fairly light, this is a much better avenue to go down.

The only time I would suggest two separate sites is when each platform needs radically different content, for example the desktop site has a lot of bells and whistles. Here you wish to keep the full desktop experience but strip it down on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is best to adopt a mobile-first responsive approach with media queries for larger display widths.  Use javaScript to lazy-load larger images only where they would be used.  It is too common that people just scale down large images for mobile, and cause others to be loaded even when they are not used in the mobile style.

Answer (score 0):

I will make two sites, either in one domain, two folders
or in two sub domains
or in two domains

But I will link them, and use JS to detect browser and ask people to switch between sites.

(or, more simple way is just change css and use fluid design)

Answer (score 0):

The state of the art can be found in this site: [www.html5rocks.com](http://www.html5rocks.com)

See this article about [a new perspective on mobile cross device sites](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/cross-device/).

Answer (score 0):

to build on David's answer and provide additional resources for your state of the art web making exploration, check this out.

http://html5boilerplate.com/

I've heard a lot of talk about mobile first development, but I think it really depends on your project.

Rather than making everything completely responsive and flexible, perhaps you may look into media queries. That's just my 2 pence.